# Table title in the middle but content on the left

Tags: tables

I write latex with IEEEtrans with TexLive version 2022.

I would like to have the header in the middle (red arrow) but the content on the left (purple arrow) as follows.

[image: expectation]

This is the code.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}

\label{tab:abbreviation} 
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth} { |
  c |
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X |}
  \hline
  \textbf{Abbreviation} & \textbf{Explanation} \\
  \hline
  ASAP  & As soon as possible \\
  \hline
  FIFO & First in first out \\
  \hline
  TBA & To be announced\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

However, the result is as follows.

[image: result]

What needs to be revised from the code?
Thank you.

Comment: `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Explanation}}` in the header.

Comment: thank you @campa, it worked!